# Unable to use Sea Glass Look and Feel together with JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, look-and-feel

When i used Sea-glass look and feel with JFreechart, the chart appreared normally but Sea-Glass didn't change the look and feel at all, although when sea-glass was used without Jfreechart, it worked.

So, what could be the reason?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
    JFreeChart chart = chart_producer(url) //my own static method to make the chart//
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    //chartPanel.setPopupMenu(null);
    //chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(false);
    panel.add(chartPanel);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
};
        }
        );
    }
```

Comment: @TU_HEO If you use another custom look-and-feel, does it behave in the same way ? Or is this behaviour specifically to SeaGlass ?

Comment: @Sobo : No, SeaGlass is my only customed look and fell till now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) is *not* a `JComponent`. It does not have a UI delegate to change. Alternatively, applying a [`ChartTheme`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartTheme.html) may be effective.

Addendum: Although a chart is not a component, it may be added to a [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) as part of an arbitrary L&F/layout, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339590/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513).

Comment: Sea-Glass doesn't work in the way that the new Jframe(with sea-glass) looks exactly the one without Sea-Glass.

Comment: @TU_HEO DAKAI you can apply Look and Feel only to the [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), `JFreeChart` is not part of a `JComponents`

Comment: @mKorbel : how about the JFrame (that contains the JFreeChart)? In my case, Sea-Glass doen't make any change to JFrame :  the min, max, close buttons...

Comment: @TU_HEO DAKAI It wrong, very wrong way to create a new JFrame, use JDialog, JWindow for popup window only, otherwise look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), for changing L&F on the runtime you have look at [SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic)

Comment: @mKorbel: is correct; more above. Frame decorations belong to the host platform.