# To set Limit for opening more Jinternalframes

Tags: java, swing

In my Project I am having `JDesktopPane` and `Jmenu`, in that menu I am having more internalFrames, I want to set a limit for the user so that the user can only open maximum three `JinternalFrames`.

I don't have any idea about how to do this, please help me.

Comment: And what have you tried? Show some efforts.

Comment: Please get some code here, then you might get some help.

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind.

The first is to extend the `JDesktopPane` and override the `addImpl` method.  In here, you can check the number of components on the desktop and stop adding when it reaches your limit.

The second is similar, basically, when menu activates you `actionPerformed` method, you check the desktop pane for how many components it contains and stop adding when you reach limit.

Comment: +1 In the second scenario, an `Action` helps enforce the rule consistently, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11385675/230513).