# How to draw an object on a Frame from an actionPerformed() method of ActionListener class

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, shapes

I am trying to draw a Shape object inside an actionPerformed() method of ActionListener class and add it to the InternalFrame.

```
public class InternalFrame extends JInternalFrame{

    public JSlider redSlider, greenSlider, blueSlider;
    public TextField redField = new TextField();
    public TextField greenField = new TextField();
    public TextField blueField = new TextField();
    Checkbox checkBox = new Checkbox("Filled", true);
    String[] shapeNames = {"Oval", "Rectangle", "Line", "NewShape"};

    public InternalFrame(String string, boolean b,
                    boolean c, boolean d, boolean e) {
        super(string,b,c,d);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        redSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 256, 32);
        greenSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 256, 32);
        blueSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 256, 32);

        redField.setText(" " + redSlider.getValue());
        greenField.setText(" " + greenSlider.getValue());
        blueField.setText(" " + blueSlider.getValue());

        redSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                redField.setText(" " + redSlider.getValue());
                //System.out.println("red value: " + redSlider.getValue());
            }
        });

        greenSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                greenField.setText(" " + greenSlider.getValue());
            }
        });

        blueSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                blueField.setText(" " + blueSlider.getValue());
            }
        });

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 6, 0));

        JComboBox shapesDropDown = new JComboBox(shapeNames);
        shapesDropDown.setSelectedIndex(0);

        shapesDropDown.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){     
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //if(arg0.getSource() == shapeNames[1] ){
                MyShape myShape = new MyRectangle();
                add(myShape, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                System.out.println("HHHH");
                //}
            }
        });

        JPanel empty1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel empty2 = new JPanel();

        topPanel.add(empty1);
        topPanel.add(shapesDropDown);
        topPanel.add(checkBox);
        topPanel.add(empty2);

        JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
        sliderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        sliderPanel.add(new Label("Red:"));
        sliderPanel.add(redSlider);
        sliderPanel.add(redField);
        sliderPanel.add(new Label("Green:"));
        sliderPanel.add(greenSlider);
        sliderPanel.add(greenField);
        sliderPanel.add(new Label("Blue:"));
        sliderPanel.add(blueSlider);
        sliderPanel.add(blueField);

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

The shape object is also getting created, however it is not getting displayed on the InternalFrame.

Comment: How do you know it's not instantiated?

Comment: How do you know it's not getting created? I mean, the only way a constructor could fail is by throwing an exception, yet you don't mention one.

Comment: Sorry, the object is getting instantiated, however the rectangle is not getting added on the Frame.

Comment: I suspect the test `if(arg0.getSource() == shapeNames[1] )` to be always false. Please add more code. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is welcome.

Comment: updated the code. removed the condition. Still the shape is not getting shown on the frame.

Comment: Note that posting an SSCCE allows people to try the code faster..  (What you posted is 'code' but not an 'SSCCE').

Comment: `revalidate()` and `repaint()`...

Comment: You can't add multiple components to the CENTER of a BorderLayout. It is also common practice to "accept" answers when you get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending `JInternalFrame`, use a factory method to create the internal frame and its content. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339590/230513), `createInternalFrame()` is called in the constructor, but it can be called from an `ActionListener` as well. Note that the internal frame's default layout is `BorderLayout`, and the default placement is `CENTER`; be sure to `pack()` the container before adjusting its size and visibility.

[image]