# Inserting a chart to a internal jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe, jchart2d

I have a program were I want to have a plotter that updates in realtime. I am going to use jchart2d, but how do I integrate that into my swing gui? I have a internalframe but it does not seem to take my chart. That is the jInternalFrame has no contents.

```
private void initObjects(){
    trace =new Trace2DLtd(200);
    trace.setColor(Color.Blue);
    Chart2D.cjart = new Chart2D();
    chart.addTrace(trace);
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().add(chart);
   }
```

later on when I update

```
 public void update()
{ trace.addPoint(elapsedtime,activity)}
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: are you using any layout for the jInternalframe1 ? Show the code how you have declared the jInterframe1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`InternalPie`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8199839/230513) is a complete example that adds a `ChartPanel` to a `JInternalFrame`.

Addendum: Like `JFrame`, `JInternalFrame` defaults to `BorderLayout` and `add()` forwards to the content pane's `BorderLayout.CENTER`; `pack()` should precede `setVisible()`.

```
ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);
JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame("Chart", ...);
jif.add(cp);
jif.pack();
jif.setVisible(true);
```

[image]